# Get n points along ellipse given endpoints & minor axis

Tags: r

I am attempting to draw an ellipse between two endpoints or what this picture calls the vertices:

[image]

In the function I want to give the coordinates of the two vertices and specify the distance of what the image calls the minor axis (perpendicular to the line created by the vertices.  I brushed off some high school math but am struggling with creating a function that gives me n values along the ellipse.  I have looked at the ellipse package but this appears to want a correlation, however, I want the function to return values like `ellipse` does.

I'm not stuck on any particular approach but would like to specify the arguments in my attempted function below.  My search of ellipse and R yielded many hits but not given the arguments I'm attempting to use.

```
elip <- function(vert1 = c(.25, .45), vert2 = c(.5, .35), minoraxis = .1, n =150) {

    majoraxis <- sqrt(((vert2[1] - vert1[1])^2) + ((vert2[2] - vert1[2])^2))
    center <- c((vert2[1] + vert1[1])/2, (vert2[2] + vert1[2])/2)
    half_ma <- minoraxis/2
    focci_dist <- sqrt(abs((majoraxis ^2) - (half_ma^2)))

}
```

Comment: FWIW, with `r` the correlation coefficient, `D` the length of the major axis, and `d` the length of the minor axis, `r = (D-d)^2/(D+d)^2`. (I took that from an interesting little paper I pull out from time to time, "Thirteen ways to look at the correlation coefficient" (Rodgers & Nicewander, 1988).)

Comment: Very useful Josh.  Thank you for sharing.  This would allow the use of `ellipse`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This takes the two vertices on the major axis and the half length of the minor axis (as b) along with the number of points.

```
halfEllipse <- function(v1, v2, b, n = 100){
    x1 <- v1[1]
    y1 <- v1[2]
    x2 <- v2[1]
    y2 <- v2[2]
    xc <- mean(c(x1,x2))
    yc <- mean(c(y1,y2))
    A <- sqrt((xc-x1)^2 + (yc-y1)^2)
    myangle <- atan((yc-y1)/(xc-x1))

    # Construct half ellipse with desired
    # major and minor axis length
    ts <- seq(0, pi, length.out = n)
    X <- A*cos(ts)
    Y <- b*sin(ts)

    # Rotate to get to desired angle
    Xp <- X*cos(myangle) - Y*sin(myangle) 
    Yp <- X*sin(myangle) + Y*cos(myangle)

    # Shift back to desired center
    Xp <- Xp + xc
    Yp <- Yp + yc

    cbind(Xp,Yp)
}
```

Comment: Still figuring out the other half of the ellipse.  Dason said in chat: "Then if you want a general ellipse you can rotate you points via a rotation matrix and then just shift them to have the center that you want"

Comment: If you want the 'other' half of the ellipse change the ts to `ts <- seq(pi, 2*pi, length.out = n)`